# CSS applied to button leaves purple box under buttons

Tags: html, css

So, I was messing with CSS for my buttons and tried to test the following CSS code on the button element:

```
button {
    width:85px;
    height:29px;
    background-color:#800080;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The 2 buttons at the end are created by this HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="search">
        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="text" style="width:80%;height:28px;background-color:#F5F5F5;font-size:16px;position:relative;top:-3px;"/>
            <button type="button" style="position:relative;top:6px;"><img src="mgt.jpg" /></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="upload" class="top-button"><button>Upload</button></div>
    <div id="signin" class="top-button"><button>Sign in</button></div>
</div>
```

Last 2 buttons "upload" and "signin" are the ones n question.

and the result:

[image: Buttons with weird purple box under them]

As viewed in Firefox. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: id="upload" please add css code for this too

Comment: Construct a jsFiddle demo and you will see for yourself what's causing what.

Comment: Ok woops. I did in fact add duplicate CSS instructions under #upload and #signin. I have no idea how I got the 2 buttons touching like that I think the upload button might just be overflowing or taking up its div container. They both are supposed to float left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the issue .... Check out http://jsfiddle.net/vb7S3/

But I would still recommend not to use `<button>` tags and rather define style classes for #upload and #signin.

HTML

```
<button id="upload" class="top-button">Upload</button>
<button id="signin" class="top-button">Sign in</button>
```

CSS

```
#upload, #signin {
    width:85px;
    height:29px;
    background-color:#800080;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Also `<button>` is tag may not be supported by all browsers.

### Better Way...

HTML

```
<input id="button" class="upload-button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
<input id="button" class="sign-in-button" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
```

CSS

```
#button {
    width:85px;
    height:29px;
    background-color:#800080;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Must include `<input>` tag inside the `<form> ... </form>` block.

Comment: Pretty much everyone pointed out what the problem was, so technically the first poster should get the point, but I thought the extra tidbit was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `height` property that's causing this, since the purple area appears to be `29 px` high. I'm not sure what the extra border below the text is, but it's possible that the border is being applied around the text instead of the entire button. Try adding `border:none` and see if that helps.

Comment: Could you also post the CSS for .top-button? I've tested this in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox and the buttons don't line up horizontally the way they do in the picture you posted. (They also don't show the additional background, so it could be a problem with the 'top-button' CSS)

Answer (score 0):

see this demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hDED/)

you issue is `id='upload'` or `id="signin"`in

```
<div id="upload" class="top-button"><button>Upload</button></div>
```

there is some conflect between the CSS for `upload` and `signin` ids, possibly , some hieght value issue